# Installing the new R Studio

Tags: windows-10, installation, r, rstudio

I tried uninstalling the old version of RStudio and then installing the new RStudio, which seemed successful. I then tried to install a package and the following error is thrown:

> install.packages("pacman")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/marin/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
>     cannot open URL 'http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
>   trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/pacman_0.5.1.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 389682 bytes (380 KB)
>   downloaded 380 KB
>
> package ‘pacman’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
>       C:\Users\marin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpglKCZL\downloaded_packages

Not really sure what the answer is but I tried uninstalling and re-installing R to see if it would help. It didn't. I also gave full permissions to R and RStudio, and that didn't help either. I'm at a loss!

Comment: Have you tried install.packages("pacman", dependencies = TRUE)?

Comment: I haven't, but is that what I would have to do with all packages from now on?

Comment: Read this: https://superuser.com/help/formatting

Comment: If that works, why not? Any update on the attempt?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that CRAN mirror hasn't been updated since 2016. Try:

```r
options(repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```